How can I solve this Shift/Reduce conflict?
I am getting shift/reduce conflict
The following is my .cup specification:
terminal           PROG, SEMI, RANGE, VOID;

terminal           PP, MM, READ, LPAREN, RPAREN, DCOL; terminal
MUL, DIV, MOD, PLUS, MINUS, NEW; terminal           LSQUARE, RSQUARE,
PRINT, EQ; terminal           LBRACE, RBRACE, COMMA, CONST; terminal
Integer   NUMBER; terminal String    IDENT; terminal char CHARCONST;
terminal String BOOLCONST;
nonterminal               program, designatorStatement, method_list;
nonterminal               addop, mulop, var_list, var_dec; nonterminal
const_list, const_dec, statement_list; nonterminal
form_pars, declaration_list, declaration_part; nonterminal
parameter_list, parameter;
nonterminal rs.etf.pp1.symboltable.concepts.Struct type, mulop_factor,
addop_term, factor_type, expr, term, addop_term_list,
mulop_factor_list, factor; nonterminal
rs.etf.pp1.symboltable.concepts.Obj progName, statement, designator,
method_type_name, method_dec, var_part, const_part, DummyArray;
program ::= (Program) PROG progName:p declaration_list LBRACE
method_list RBRACE;
progName ::= (ProgName) IDENT:progName;
method_list ::= (MethodList) method_list method_dec
|
(NoMethods) /* epsilon */
;
method_dec ::= (MethodDecl) method_type_name LPAREN form_pars RPAREN
declaration_list LBRACE statement_list RBRACE;
method_type_name ::= (MethodTypeName) type: methodType IDENT:
methodName
|
(MethodTypeNameVoid) VOID IDENT: methodName
;
form_pars ::= (ParamList) parameter_list
|
(NoParams) /* epsilon */;
parameter_list ::= (ParamListDecl) parameter_list COMMA parameter
|
(ParamDecl) parameter;
parameter ::= (ParamType) type IDENT
|         (ParamArray) type IDENT LSQUARE RSQUARE;
declaration_list ::= (DeclList) declaration_list declaration_part
|
(NoDeclList) /* epsilon */
;
declaration_part ::= (DeclPartConstDecl) const_dec
|
(DeclPartVarDecl) var_dec
;
var_dec ::= (VarDecl) type:varType var_list SEMI      |        (VarDeclVal)
type:varType var_list EQ factor_type SEMI          ;
var_list ::= (VarListDecl) var_list COMMA var_part
|
(VarPart) var_part
;
var_part ::= (VarPartDecl) IDENT:varName
|
(VarPartArrDecl) IDENT:varName LSQUARE RSQUARE
|
(VarPartMatrixDecl) IDENT:varName LSQUARE RSQUARE LSQUARE RSQUARE
;
const_dec ::= (ConstDeclVal) CONST type: varType const_list SEMI;
const_list ::= (ConstListDecl) const_list COMMA const_part
|
(ConstPart) const_part
;
const_part ::= (ConstPartDecl) IDENT: varName EQ factor_type;
statement_list ::= (StatementListDecl) statement_list statement
|
/* epsilon */
;
statement ::= (StatementDSDecl) designatorStatement SEMI
|
(StatementReadDecl) READ LPAREN designator RPAREN SEMI
|
(StatementPrintDecl) PRINT LPAREN expr RPAREN SEMI
|
(StatementPrintNumConstDecl) PRINT LPAREN expr COMMA NUMBER: id RPAREN SEMI
;
designatorStatement ::= (DesignatorEQDecl) designator: id EQ expr
|
(DesignatorPPDecl) designator: id PP
|
(DesignatorMMDecl) designator: id MM
;
expr ::= (ExprAddopTermDeclMinus) MINUS term addop_term_list
|
(ExprAddopTermDecl) term addop_term_list
;
term ::= (TermDecl) factor mulop_factor_list;
addop_term_list ::= (AddopTermListDecl) addop_term_list addop_term
|
(NoAddopTermListDecl) /* epsilon */
;
addop_term ::= (AddopTermDecl) addop term;
mulop_factor_list ::= (MulopFactorListDecl) mulop_factor_list
mulop_factor
|
(NoMulopFactorListDecl) /* epsilon */
;
mulop_factor ::= (MulopFactorDecl) mulop factor;
factor ::= (FactorType) factor_type
|
(FactorExprDecl) LPAREN expr RPAREN
|
(FactorDesignatorDecl) designator
|
(FactorTypeArrDecl) NEW type: t LSQUARE expr RSQUARE
|
(FactorTypeMatrixDecl) NEW type: t LSQUARE expr RSQUARE LSQUARE expr RSQUARE
|
(FactorRangeDecl) RANGE LPAREN expr RPAREN
;
factor_type ::= (FactorNumberDecl) NUMBER
|
(FactorCharDecl) CHARCONST
|
(FactorBooleanDecl) BOOLCONST
;
designator ::= (DesignatorDcolDecl) IDENT DCOL IDENT
|
(DesignatorArrDecl) DummyArray LSQUARE expr RSQUARE
|
(DesignatorMatrixDecl) DummyArray LSQUARE expr RSQUARE LSQUARE expr RSQUARE
|
(DesignatorDecl) IDENT: id
;
DummyArray ::= (DummyArray) designator;
addop ::= (AddopPlus) PLUS
|
(AddopMinus) MINUS
;
mulop ::= (MulopMul) MUL
|
(MulopDiv) DIV
|
(MulopMod) MOD
;
type ::= (Type) IDENT: id;

This is the problematic block, that is causing the conflict:
designator ::= (DesignatorDcolDecl) IDENT DCOL IDENT
            |
            (DesignatorArrDecl) DummyArray LSQUARE expr RSQUARE
            |
            (DesignatorMatrixDecl) DummyArray LSQUARE expr RSQUARE 
    LSQUARE expr RSQUARE
            |
            (DesignatorDecl) IDENT: id
            ;

This is the error I get when I try to generate parser using cup:
 [java]   between designator ::= DummyArray LSQUARE expr RSQUARE (*) 
 [java]   and     designator ::= DummyArray LSQUARE expr RSQUARE (*) LSQUARE expr RSQUARE 
 [java]   under symbol LSQUARE
 [java]   Resolved in favor of shifting.
 [java]   Checking for non-reduced productions...

How can I resolve this conflict and why am I not getting the same error for example here:
    |
    (FactorTypeArrDecl) NEW type: t LSQUARE expr RSQUARE
    |
    (FactorTypeMatrixDecl) NEW type: t LSQUARE expr RSQUARE LSQUARE expr RSQUARE

Sorry for formating of the cup specification, but I was unable to post the question otherwise.

Where does the shift/reduce conflict come from?
This is caused by the DummyArray nonterminal that is defined as:
(1): DummyArray ::= designator

Take the productions as shown by the parser (As part of the conflict analysis):
(2): designator ::= DummyArray LSQUARE expr RSQUARE
(3): designator ::= DummyArray LSQUARE expr RSQUARE LSQUARE expr RSQUARE

If we apply a substitution on the first productionrule of designator using the fact that DummyArray is simply a designator we can translate the production to:
designator ::= DummyArray LSQUARE expr RSQUARE
             (1)= designator LSQUARE expr RSQUARE
             (2)= DummyArray LSQUARE expr RSQUARE LSQUARE expr RSQUARE

So we can translate rule 2 into 3 due to DummyArray. This means that the grammar is ambiguous and thus it guarantees a conflict. In this case it is in the form of a shift/reduce conflict.
Solution
The most simple solution is to simply remove DummyArray.
Another solution is to make the DummyArray not contain a production rule having only designator in it.
Other solutions depend on your goals which only you can decide.
